# Unbalanced client size in federated learning

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am applying federated learning on multiple files using Tensoflow Federated. The problem is, that the size of data (number of records) in each file is different.

1. Is it a problem in federated learning training to have different sizes for each client? if there is how can I overcome it?
2. Is there a way that I can see how each client performing while federated computation training?

[image: The chart describing the variety of number of records in each client]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it a problem in federated learning training to have different sizes for each client? if there is how can I overcome it?

This depends on a variety of factors, a large one being the data distribution on the clients. For example, if each clients data looks *very* similar (e.g. effectively the same distribution, [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)) it doesn't particularly matter which client is used.

If this isn't the case, a common technique is to limit the number of *maximum* steps a client takes on its dataset each round, to promote more equal participation in the training process. In TensorFlow and TFF this can be accomplished using [`tf.data.Dataset.take`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly#take) to restrict to a maximum number of iterations. In TFF this can be applied to every client using [`tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.preprocess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData#preprocess). This is discussed with examples in the tutorial [Working with TFF's ClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/working_with_client_data).

#### Is there a way that I can see how each client performing while federated computation training?

Clients can return individual metrics to report how they are performing, but this isn't done by default. In [`tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/algorithms/build_weighted_fed_avg)  the `metrics_aggregator` defaults to [`tff.learning.metrics.sum_then_finalize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/metrics/sum_then_finalize) which in usually creates global averages of metrics. There isn't an out-of-the-box solution, but one could implement a "finalize-then-sample" that would likely meet this need. Re-using [`tff.aggregators.federated_sample`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/aggregators/federated_sample) and looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.24.0/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/metrics/aggregator.py#L129-L186) for `sum_then_finalize` as an example would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, Dr. for this detailed answer. All of the files are having the same distribution so I guess it is IID. Well, since there is a big variety of client sizes, how can I choose which are the training and testing clients? Is there a certain rule or it is taken randomly? I am planning to take 2 for testing and the rest are for training.